# Need to grant db_reader permission on one database while db_writer on another for the same service account

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking at script that will grant `db_reader` & `db_writer` roles on a table for a service account in SQL Server 2008 R2. I am looking at granting these permissions only to specific databases. The same service account will have db_reader permissions on one table while db_writer on others

Comment: I am looking at database level and not table level

Comment: I tried this but it getting syntax error in the To section.  GRANT SELECT ON CoreReferenceStaging TO 'INT\svc-w-corerefdata-de'

Comment: I thought you where looking for a way to assign `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles to a user. If that is the case, then it is a duplicate. If not, your question is not very clear.

Comment: I am looking at applying to user for a specific database. so assume you have service account xyz. I need to give xyz  db_reader permission on database A and db_writer permission on database d. Cant explain beyond that

Comment: Please let me know where in that article shows the solution for my problem

Comment: Did you try `sp_addrolemember` as mentioned in the accepted answer?

Comment: That will grant the role for all the databases on the server for a user.

Comment: No, it wont. db_datareader and db_datawriter are [database level roles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121(v=sql.90).aspx).

Comment: so how do you grant db_datareader  for a specific database. sp_addrolemember db_datareader  grants role to user for all databases

Comment: No, it will not. It will only grant db_datareader to the for database that you where connected to when you executed the stored procedure! Try it on a test database and see for yourself!